# Select random visible row from table and clone it (with JS/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, random

I'm trying to get one random row from an array which is composed of 100 rows. Some are hidden, other are visible.

My aim is to get a random visible row, and clone it in another table. (visible and hidden row are classified, that's why I need that !)

My code:

```
<table id="Random">
</table>

<table id="Classified">
    <tr id="Row1" style="display:none">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="Row2">
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="Row3" style="display:none">
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="Row4">
        <td>13</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>43</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="Row5">
        <td>15</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>48</td>
    </tr>
</table>    


<script>
    $("#Random").html("");
    var randomtd = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#Classified tr:visible').length) + 1;
    var identifiedRow = $('#Classified tr').eq(randomtd)[0];

    $("#Random").html(identifiedRow);    
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any issue with the current code you have?

Comment: For now, it will take the lenght of every td... So sometime I can clone a visible td, and other time, it will clone an hidden td.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in these lines:

```
var randomtd = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#Classified tr:visible').length)+1;
var identifiedRow = $('#Classified tr').eq(randomtd)[0];
```

Change them to:

```
var randomtd = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#Classified tr:visible').length);
var identifiedRow = $('#Classified tr:visible').eq(randomtd)[0];
```

jQuery [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) requires an integer indicating the 0-based position of the element.

```js
$("#Random").html("");
var randomtd = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#Classified tr:visible').length);
var identifiedRow = $('#Classified tr:visible').eq(randomtd);

//$("#Random").html(identifiedRow);
$("#Random").append(identifiedRow.clone());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Random table: <br/>
<table id="Random">
</table>
Classified table: <br/>
<table id="Classified">
    <tr id="Row1" style="display:none">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="Row2">
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="Row3" style="display:none">
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="Row4">
        <td>13</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>43</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="Row5">
        <td>15</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>48</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's work, but it seems to cut/paste the line instead of copy/paste. Maybe with clone ? $("#Random").clone().append(identifiedRow); ?

Comment: @OverSu If you don't want to cut/paste but copy/paste the row: **$("#Random").append(identifiedRow.clone());**. Snippet updated. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/1hok7xme/

```js
$("#Random").html("");
   
$('#Classified tr').each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':visible')){
    $("#Random").append(`<tr>${$(this).html()}</tr>`);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Random Table:
<table id="Random">
</table>

<br/>
Classified Table:
<table id="Classified">
    <tr id="Row1" style="display:none">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="Row2">
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="Row3" style="display:none">
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="Row4">
        <td>13</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>43</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="Row5">
        <td>15</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>48</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This also works. But it takes every visible rows. With my code, I'm trying to random one. :o

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it ! Thanks to everyone. Each+Array. ;)

```
        var arrayTmp = [];
            var i = 0;
            $('.Monstres tbody tr').each(function(){
              if($(this).is(':visible')){
                arrayTmp[i] = '<tr>'+$(this).html()+'</tr>';
                i++;
              }
            });
            var arrayTmp = arrayTmp[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayTmp.length)];
            $(".Random table").append(arrayTmp);
```